# expansion for outcome's estimate of a single draw from a probability distribution

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, expected-value

Limit theorems, like CLT, are useful to obtain an estimate of the sum (or the mean) of a big number of draw from a given probability distribution $P_x(x)$. 
I have a fat tail probability distribution (second moment is not defined); can I estimate, with a similar expansion approach, the outcome of a single draw from $P_x(x)$? 
Of course the difference (and the hurdle), with respect to the limit theorems case, is that, in this case, I'm not considering a quantity (like the mean) whose distribution narrows increasing the number of draws.

Comment: The [law of large numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_large_numbers) applies if the expectation is finite even if the variance is infinite, though convergence may be slow.

Comment: Apart from that, the real problem is that the limit theorems are useless on a single outcome. I can't use them for my purpose